# How to identify source of log message in a simple log analyzer application

Tags: java, logging, text-parsing, log-analysis

I am trying to create a centralize log repository project for my final year project.

Following will be the flow of my project:-
1. Receive the logs from different sources like syslog, java apps, logstash etc.
2. These logs can be received over http, tcp/udp ports etc.
3. Parse the received logs and convert them to JSON.
4. store the JSON in mongo DB.

Now I have completed the support to receive the log messages over TCP and HTTP.

**But I am not sure how to identify the log format and parse it.**
As I am getting log messages from different log sources, I can't think of a way to map a log message to it's correct parser implementation.

**Let's say over a TCP port, I am getting syslog messages, Apache logs and Java application logs and also logstash processed logs. I am getting these log entries one by one, now how can I identify the correct format/parser for each log message?**

I know that ELK stack exists for such things, but here my emphasis is on trying these things and learn as much as possible.

Comment: I believe the bigger issue is that you aren't using the same logging format for all your different applications.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz This is where I am trying to do something interesting. I want to support parsing of multiple formats in my project. All of them are known formats and I have written the parser for them, the only thing giving me problem is how to redirect a message to it's correct parser.

Comment: you should show all the possible formats, or you could have a socket set up per application so based on which socket receives the message you know where it came from

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz, Thanks for suggestion, this sounds like a good approach. I would try this one and see how it turns out. I was also interested in some approach like loggely where they identify the message format without any dependency on how it was transported.